# Send multi word string in expect script

Tags: bash, expect

First of all, I'm new to expect scripting...

I'm using RHEL 5.6 Linux.

I want to call an expect script out from a bash script and pass it two arguments, 
a subject and a body variable (read from a file and stored in it) in order for the 
expect script to send emails with that subject and body.

use_expect.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash  
body=`cat body.txt`
subj="whatever bla bla"
./mail.exp $subj $body
```

mail.exp:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
set subj [lindex $argv 0];
set body [lindex $argv 3]; # here we see also: instead of 1 I have to use 3 to skip all the subj words
spawn telnet localhost 25
.
.
.
send "mail from:...\n"
send "rcpt to:...\n"
send "data\n"
send "Subject: $subj\n"    # only the first word is being sent!!!
send "$body\n"             # also only the first word is being sent!!!
...
send "quit\n"
interact
```

Answer (score 1):

In the bash script, you have to quote your variables:

```
./mail.exp "$subj" "$body"
```

That will ensure the values are not split up by the shell before invoking the expect script.

Now, `set body [lindex $argv 1]` will work as expected.

For your `send` statements, use `\r` instead of `\n` -- `\r` is a carriage return which simulates the user hitting Enter.

More details in the bash manual: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Word-Splitting

Note that, unless you're doing this to learn expect, this is not really the right tool for automating email. I'd start with

```
{
    echo "From: me@domain.invalid"
    echo "To: you@example.com"
    echo "Subject: $subject"
    echo
    echo "$body"
} | /usr/sbin/sendmail -oi -t
```

Comment: Many thanks @Glenn. Yes, I tried it first with sendmail but I didn't see a possibility to use a remote smtp server...  With your help it works at least fine and more comfortable for a local smtp server..